# postIndex() doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-routing

I just moved my register to the front page of my website.
My routes are like this:

```
   Route::controller('/user', 'UserController');
   Route::controller('/page', 'PageController');

   Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

When I post on the form it doesn't execute the postIndex() method in my HomeController for some reason. I can't figure out why. It's just a return statement with some text for now to test.

My form looks like this

```
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'class'=>'form', 'role' => 'form', 'id' => 'register-form')) }}
        {{ Form::text('username', $value = null, array('placeholder' => 'Username', 'class'=> 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus' )) }}
        {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'password', 'required' => 'required')) }}
        {{ Form::text('email', $value = null, array('placeholder' => 'Email', 'class'=> 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Sign up', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-default')) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the HTTP method to your form.  Without it defined, and no route used, it should default to GET, but you want POST.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'post', 'class'=>'form', 'role' => 'form', 'id' => 'register-form')) }}
```